# An almost surly fine-time game of coin toss where you win with probability $p$

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

Given a fair coin and a number $p\in(0,1)$. How do you design a game that finishes in a finite number of tosses with a probability of $1$? And further, with the probability $p$ you win the game.

I thought about random walks where the head, you add 1, tail you subtract 1. And you want to get to $n$. But that gives an approximation to $p$ and not $p$.

Comment: You don't have an question in your post.

Comment: Toss the fair coin$\lceil{e{^\pi}\Gamma(\pi^e p)}\rceil$ times. Then draw a single U[0,1]} random number,,$x$ from an r.n.g. If $x \le p$, you win, otherwise you lose.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your random walk approach is you cannot ensure with probability $1$ that you eventually get to a value of $n$. In fact, using Chernoff's inequality, you can show that the probability you reach the value $n$ gets quite small as $n$ grows. Thus, your game may struggle to actually terminate in a finite number of steps.

---

At first glance, this question is a little bit complicated since we consider *any* real value $p$ within the interval $(0,1)$. I will not worry about something that is perfect for any value $p$, but something that gets close using a finite number of fair coin flips.

Now consider fixing some sufficiently large positive integer $m$. Flip the coin $m$ times and store results as bits in an $m$-bit integer $k$. If coin flip $i$ is a heads, the $i^{th}$ bit of $k$ is a $1$ and is otherwise set to $0$. Notice that with $m$ bits, there are $2^m$ possible integer values that $k$ can take on ranging between $0$ and $2^m - 1$. Using our value for $k$ generated by the fixed number of coin flips, we will compute $x = \frac{k}{2^m - 1}$, which gives $x$ a value within the interval $[0,1]$. We can then return that one wins the game iff $x \leq p$.

---

Now to consider the correctness of the above, it is clear the algorithm terminates in a finite amount of time since we only need to flip the coin $m$ times, compute $x$, and compute the boolean value $x \leq p$. Now if we were to visualize all the possible $2^m$ values that $x$ could be, the visualization would be a collection of equally spaced points contained in the interval $[0,1]$, where each point is a distance of $\delta = 2^{-m}$ away from its nearest neighboring point. For any given $p$, the probability of our coin flips generating a value $x$ that makes us win is then equal to

$$\text{Pr}\lbrace \text{winning with } x \rbrace = \hat{p} = \frac{\lfloor p(2^m-1)\rfloor + 1}{2^{m}}$$

The above can be found by counting the number of complete intervals of size $\delta$ contained in the interval $[0,p]$, call this $N_{I \subseteq [0,p]}$, and then noticing that the number of points within $[0,p]$ is equal to the number $N_{I \subseteq [0,p]} + 1$. By then dividing the number of points within $[0,p]$ by the total number of $2^m$ points gives us the probability that $x$, computed by our algorithm, will satisfy $x \leq p$. Ideally, the probability of winning under this algorithm would equal $p$ for any value of $p$, but this is hard to achieve purely by coin flips. Thus, we can find that for any $p \in (0,1)$ that

$$\left| p - \hat{p} \right| \leq 2^{-m}$$

which implies we can exponentially shrink the error between the algorithm's win probability and the desired win probability using only a polynomial number of coin flips. By just setting $m = 1000$, for example, we have that the absolute difference $|p - \hat{p}|$ is at most $10^{-301}$, which implies the algorithm with this fixed value of $m$ will allow one to win with a probability pretty dang close to the desired value!